# How can I know were my users downloaded my Electron app?

Tags: electron, tracking

I have a Electron App, you register an account in the app after installing it, but when I run campaigns, how can I know if they came from the campaign page or the regular landingpage?

Can I read cookies from the browser? Or maybe send a textfile with the app which I read from when they install the app?

Comment: Are you trying to tell from within Electron, what URL was used to download it to their computer, but only AFTER registration has occurred?  I believe you will need to either used [advanced fingerprinting](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/now-sites-can-fingerprint-you-online-even-when-you-use-multiple-browsers/) to identify the same the user (frowned upon) or offer a slightly customized download that helps identify where they came from.  Note that something as subtle as changing the installer name (e.g. `My App` to `My App Installer`) could be subtle enough to detect.

Comment: Can't you simply ask the respective web server providing these pages? You don't want to stalk your users, do you? The statistics about the success of the campaign should suffice...

Comment: @tref Changing the installation file name would be a simple and nice solution, but does that mean I must know the exact path to the file? Meaning, if they change the path from the standard, I lose the tracking?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.